# C++ Function will not execute more than once

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I've tried looking around but I can't find anything about this anywhere.

I'm writing a custom array class with a "push" function to add a value to the array.
It seems to work perfectly fine but won't execute more than once.

Take the main method below for example:

```
int main()
{
    Array<int> test(4,5);
    test.push(4);

    test.writeOrdered("Output.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

This will put the int value 4 into the array at the first available position and execute the writeOrdered function.

The following main method, on the other hand:

```
int main()
{
    Array<int> test(4,5);
    test.push(4);
    test.push(5);

    test.writeOrdered("Output.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

This will put the number 4 into the array at the first available point as above and then stop. It won't execute any further lines of code.

Here's the `push` function for reference:

```
void push(Datatype p_item)
{
    bool inserted = false;
    int i = 0;

    while (inserted == false)
    {
        if (m_array[i] < 0)
        {
            m_array[i] = p_item;
            i++;
            inserted = true;
            cout << p_item << " saved to array" << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's an `Array<int>`?

Comment: what does the `system("pause");` do? Maybe you just need to press enter?

Comment: Are you allocating memory for each new element?  if not, you are just assigning a pointer, and when you try to insert at incremented i it will crash

Comment: I'd added the cout and system("pause") just for debugging so I could find out where it was stopping

Comment: an Array<int> is an array of integers, the Array class I have operates using Datatypes to make it more flexible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an infinite loop. After the first insert `m_array[0] >= 0` and `i` never grows. You would have found it out, had you debugged the code somehow.

Comment: Yes, you need to increment i in the negative case as well as the affirmative.

Comment: That was it, I knew it was something silly, thanks! :)

I had breakpoints throughout the loop but for whatever reason they only worked on the first iteration so it didn't look like an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I don't understand your push function but the way it is, after you insert a non-negative value into the first position any further call to your push function results in a tight loop.

I imagine that you want the i++ outside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full implementation of the Array class I would guess that the array `m_array` contains negative numbers by default. This will allow the first call to the push method to succeed. The next call to the method contains a value of 4 at index 0 and will be stuck in an infinite loop because `inserted` will never be set to true nor will the value of `i` be incremented.